# how to export mdb to dgn file in qgis

Tags: qgis, export, file-formats

I am having an (.mdb) file .I want to export this file to (.dgn) format .How can i do this in Qgis ? Is there any plugin available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your mdb is an ESRI Personal geodatabase, you can add it to your QGIS project with `Add vector layer`.

Then you can save the layer(s) with `rightclick -> Save as` to Microstation DGN format, with some limitations listed here:

http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_dgn.html